# Upload Multiple Images to Specific DB column in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm cracking my head on the best way to upload Multiple different/separated images and insert it into different database columns.

I would like to know the best approach of inserting multiple different images.

1. HTML5 multiple upload : This is good. I can upload all the image names in one column and separate it on the display as PHP. Issue: importing using this one does not have any control on the arrangement so it would be impossible to create a FIXED PHP code to display. Unless I rename all the image files to 1,2,3,4,5.
2. Multiple Input fields: It's a ton load of PHP code to process each Image upload.

Here's a sample DB where there are 5 image columns:

```
CREATE TABLE `hero_guide` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
      `image1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `image2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `image3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `image4` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `image5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I need to insert 5 different image in the DB because I want to insert the image files to the specific columns to retrieve it.

If I insert it in 1 db column it will look like this in the database:

```
image_sample.jpg, image_taurus.jpg, image_test29.png
```

And if I have multiple rows of this. It would be impossible for me to display correctly based on array list.

As for the datatype. I think it should be fine for now.

Answer (score -1):

There are many things that you should clarify :

1. Why You need 5 columns of images when 1 is enough ?
2. Is varchar(255) enough for your images ? I mean what's the average size of your images ?

What you could do is store your images as files then add their paths to your database.

[Edit]

Alright if you want to have many columns you can do so. But if you want to add a new column. Think of maybe having N columns. Why don't you have a new table for grouping the tables as you like. It would be easier to store your groups in the database as the filename of your images will be unique supposing that you save them in the same directory.

Comment: I would like to insert different images to different fields to easily retrieve and display the images from the DB